# how to append an element between two elements

Tags: jquery, html, append

I have a List

```
     <ul>
           <li id="lst1"> list item One</li>
           <li id="lst2"> list item two</li>
           <li id="lst3"> list item three</li>
           <li id="lst4"> list item four</li>
           <li id="lst5"> list item five</li>
     </ul>
```

and i want to append an item **between** (not inside) "lst2" and "lst3" 
i don't know how using jquery.
Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
$('#lst3').before('<li id="lst21"> list item three</li>');
```

You may try this.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `after`[<sup>**doc**</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/after/) or `insertAfter`[<sup>**doc**</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/):

```
$('#lst2').after('a');
$('a').insertAfter('#lst2');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `insertAfter()`:

```
$('<li id="newListElement" />').text('new list item').insertAfter('#lst2');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bjSjy/).

References:

- [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/).